# A relation between 3 tables Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oop

I'm trying to create an API resource, where I can view a response build from three tables.

1. Store
2. Orders
3. Purchases

Currently, I can go to a store (there are multiple stores) using routes (api/store/orders) and view the orders in a JSON response.

*response*

```
{
 data: [
  {
   id: 1,
   code: "1f",
   status: "waiting",
   user_name: "Salman",
   created_at: "",
   updated_at: ""
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   code: "2f",
   status: "waiting",
   user_name: "Jerome",
   created_at: "",
   updated_at: ""
  }
 ]
}
```

However, when I try to add my purchases to the response with:

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Orderresource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'code' => $this->code,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            // Added purchases
            'order' => $this->purchases,
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

I get met with an error response `Undefined property: stdClass::$purchases`

Now I've added purchases to my order model with:

```
  public function purchases()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class);
  }
```

However, I know that the order may lie with my `show_order_per_store.`

function in my `OrderController`

```
    public function show_order_per_club($id)
    {
      $order = DB::table('orders')->where('store_id', '=', $id)->get();


      return  Orderresource::collection($order);
    }
```

Now, this function gets all orders with similar stores, but how do I add the purchases to the stores API response?

In short, I'm trying to get an API response per store with the orders it has, and the purchases belong to that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `DB:table` for querying, try using the model directly:

```
Order::where('store_id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Seems `DB:table` returns `stdClass` objects, so it lacks all the virtual attributes that a model might provide.

Comment: thank you will try to see if this method can work. Could you explain to me a bit more what `::where` does?

Comment: @Salman Its a standard SQL where clause. It does the same thing as `DB::table()->where()`, only the query has the appropriate table name set automatically.